# How can I play a system sound with Python?

Tags: python, programming, application-development

I am writing a small reminder-app and want to play a system sound once the timer has reached 0. What is the easiest way to play that sound, and which sound would you recommend?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to shell out:

```
system("/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id='bell'")
```

This will work in other programming languages as well.

`/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play` will play a sound from the current sound theme. See the freedesktop.org [sound naming spec](http://0pointer.de/public/sound-naming-spec.html) for a list of available sounds and their meanings. Beware that (as far as I know) there isn't a sound theme that provides all of these sounds.

Use `ls /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo` to see what sounds are supported by the 'ubuntu' sound theme which is default, and rarely changed (due to no easy way to install sound themes) on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any hint on where I can find more ids? Because 'bell' does not really suit me.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: For safety, I recommend using `subprocess`. String-based execution can lead to dangerous situations. For example: `import subprocess; subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play','--id','bell'])`

Comment: @Kees Cook, Please explain how executing the above command via system() can lead to "dangerous situations".

Answer (score 2):

The following works in Linux and MacOS (haven't tried Windows):

```
print('\a')
```

Comment: Note that for this to work, the terminal setting for audible bell should be enabled. The exact name and location of the setting depends on the terminal. For example, for my kitty terminal I have to edit `~/.config/kitty/kitty.conf` and set `enable_audio_bell yes`.